# How to do unattended recording

Tags: audio-recording, software, wav

I am trying to record audio from a microphone connected to my computer for a duration of several hours, but I need to start and stop the recording without human intervention (I am using `cron` jobs).

I tried to use `parec` but it seems that the recording is forever. So I tried to kill the process automatically but with bad results (resulting WAV file says it has only a small part of the intended recording).

I tried to use `arecord` also without success: triggers an error - device not available...

The parameters are: rate=44100 format=S16LE file-format=WAV device=alsa_input.usb-0c76_SIZHENG-00.analog-mono

I am using Ubuntu Server 18.04 LTS in an old computer (i386) and I had `alsa` and `pulseaudio` installed.
I am not using any GUI...

How can I do the recording?

Comment: idk for nix, but in case anyone searches this question in future & needs a solution for Mac, then [Audio Hijack](https://rogueamoeba.com/audiohijack/) is the perfect solution [though not cheap]